Error al Descargar Google Docs como Pdf con playright
estoy intentando crear una automatización con Playright la cual consiste, en que le mando una url como parametro, la url es de un archivo en Google Docs, el cual se descarga como archivo Pdf, al lanzar el script se descarga correctamente como pdf, pero al abrir el archivo no se visualizan las imagenes.

Comparto el código que estoy usando
def download_pdf(self):
    event = self.body['urls']
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(args=["--single-process"], headless=False)
        browser.new_context(java_script_enabled=True)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=en&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin")
        page.wait_for_selector('input[type="email"]')
        page.fill('input[type="email"]', EMAIL_GOOGLE)
        page.click("#identifierNext")
        page.wait_for_selector('input[type="password"]')
        page.fill('input[type="password"]', PASSWORD_GOOGLE)
        page.wait_for_selector("#passwordNext", state="visible")
        with page.expect_navigation():
               page.click("#passwordNext")
           for item in event:
               print("Processing: ", item["url"])
               filename = f"EJ_{item['filename']}.pdf"
               file_path = f"/tmp/{filename}"
               print("file_path: ", file_path)
               page.goto(item["url"])
               page.wait_for_load_state("load")
               page.wait_for_selector("div.kix-appview-editor")
               page.emulate_media(media="print")
               pdf_bytes = page.pdf(
                   path=file_path,
                   prefer_css_page_size=True
               )
               print("PDF saved")
            browser.close()

Gracias y espero puedan ayudarme.
